# Memoize callback coming from React class component as closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

During the conversion of class components to functional component with hooks, I came across a scenario which I will try to recreate with a simple example:

I have

- Parent component as class component `ParentClass`
- Child component as a functional component with hooks `ChildComponent`

My parent component `ParentClass` passes an inline arrow function to `ChildComponent` as a prop

**parent.jsx** (which is a class component)

```js
// inside render method
render () {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      ["component1", "component2"].map((c) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={c}
          setParentItem={
            (item) => {
              // ... some more logics involving values available in
              // curernt scope only. (for example c)
              this.setState({
                component: c,
                item,
              });
            }
          }
        />
      ))
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

**child.jsx** (which is a functional component)

```js
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({});

/**
  * Here in the dependency array of useEffect
  * eslint-plugin-react asks to add setParentItem as dependency
  * which should be memoized because from the parent component it is
  * passed as an inline arrow function.
  * How can I resolve this?
  */
useEffect(() => {
  setParentItem(selectedItem);    // setParentItem retrieved via props from ParentClass component
}, [selectedItem]);    // Here; adding setParentItem in dependency array will cause infinite render
```

How can I memoize `setParentItem` so that after adding it to the dependency array of `useEffect` in the `ChildComponent`, render will not get stuck in an infinite loop?

Please also have a look at the **[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memoize-class-callback-kt7xi?file=/src/components/parent.jsx:603-1274)** for working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it as field of the class component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  setParentItem = () => {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    // ...

    <ChildComponent
          setParentItem={this.setParentItem}
    />

    // ...
  }
}
```

Now, when your callback use closures you cant do it that simply. In this case you have to change your code so it doesn't create closures. I.e. make `ChildComponent` to forward value:

```
function ChildComponent({ setParentItem, component, ...props }) {
  // ...
  setParentItem(selectedItem, component);
}
```